# angular 6 meta tags not working on lazy loading app, using angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

### blog.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',    component: BlogHomeComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component:  BlogPostsComponent}
    ] 
  }
];
```

### BlogPostComponent.ts

```
constructor(
    private meta: Meta,
    private title: Title){}

ngOnInit() {    
    this.meta.addTags([
      {name: 'description', content: 'dummy description'},
      {name: 'author', content: 'dummy name'},
      {name: 'keywords', content: 'dummy keywords'}
    ]); 
}
```

This code is working in normal component, but if i keep this code in lazy loading component with children then it is not working

I need to display the meta tags in view-source.

[image]
[image]